# Reading a video in OpenCV

Tags: opencv3.0

While working with video in OpenCV using Python, when we are reading the frames using

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret,frame=cap.read()
```

What do the variables `ret` and `frame` store?

Answer (score 0):

**Reference Material:** [Getting Started with Videos](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

`ret,frame=cap.read()`

From the documentation above:

> `cap.read()` returns a `bool` (True/False). If frame is read correctly, it
>   will be `True`. So you can check end of the video by checking this
>   return value.

So in assence,

`ret = True` or `ret = False` based on whether a frame was read correctly and `frame` is the actual frame that was read (provided `ret == True`)